# Visual Studio 2015 XAML designer view exception

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, designer

In my Visual Studio 2015, XAML designer view fails to load MainWindow.xaml which is pretty big with a pretty big Style.xaml for a resource.
It only happens in x64 configuration, goes away when I switch to x86 and recompile.
The exception I get is
InvalidOperationException: PixelShader must be set on ShaderEffect.
The stack trace does not point to any line numbers and has none of the files of my code listed so that's a dead end.
The app runs fine and shows the MainWindow it's just the designer.
Removing some lines or even some whitespace from the xaml some times seems to make it load, but only temporarily it will eventually then crash with "System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Designer process terminated unexpectedly!".

Stack trace:
           at System.Windows.Media.Effects.ShaderEffect.ManualUpdateResource(Channel channel, Boolean skipOnChannelCheck)
           at System.Windows.Media.Effects.ShaderEffect.UpdateResource(Channel channel, Boolean skipOnChannelCheck)
           at System.Windows.Media.Effects.ShaderEffect.AddRefOnChannelCore(Channel channel)
           at System.Windows.Media.Effects.Effect.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(Channel channel)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateEffect(Channel channel, ResourceHandle handle, VisualProxyFlags flags, Boolean isOnChannel)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
           at System.Windows.Media.Visual.Render(RenderContext ctx, UInt32 childIndex)
           at System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Compile(Channel channel)
           at System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget.Render(Boolean inResize, Channel channel)
           at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
           at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
           at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
           at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
           at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: Is it a custom effect (and the ShaderEffect is in the same solution code)?

Comment: @David: No it is not a custom shader. Also i don't know which effect it is referring to. There are many effects in that  Style.xaml but they are all standard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same stack trace also on an x64 configuration. I decided to work round the problem by only applying the effect if we are not in design mode.

In my case I have an image I want to appear disabled when IsEnabled=False. Adding an additional trigger to check a NotInDesignMode property on the view model did the trick.

```
<Style x:Key="GreyImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=NotInDesignMode}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Effect" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <local:GreyscaleEffect DesaturationFactor="0.0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I set NotInDesignMode in my main window's constructor and I have it as a static property in my viewmodel base class.

```
bool notInDesignMode = !DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);
```

Interestingly I didn't get the error if I used System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect instead.